# How to Get Data From One Array of Objects into another in Array of Objects in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a get request in a component that returns a response

```
  getPaymentIntents():Observable<Payment>>{
    const url: string = 'https://store.com//payments';

    return this.http.get<Payment>>
    (url);
  }
```

The response data looks something like this (the "Payment" type)

```
[
    {
        "id": "pi_3K4B432423dqM1gTYncsL",
        "amount": 2000,
        "amount_capturable": 0,
        "amount_received": 0,
        "application": null,
        "canceled_at": null,
        "cancellation_reason": null,
        "created": 1638911287,
        "currency": "usd",
        "customer": "cus_KjDBkdsaHIT6AN"
},
    {
        "id": "pi_3K4BW7EE9YQoA1qM1gTYncsL",
        "amount": 1000,
        "amount_capturable": 0,
        "amount_received": 0,
        "application": null,
        "canceled_at": null,
        "cancellation_reason": null,
        "created": 1638913687,
        "currency": "usd",
        "customer": "cus_KjDBkxEVHIT6AN"
}
]
```

I want this data to be in a "Material Table" https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

But I only want it to display a subset of the data. (In the future I will want to combine another response's data into the table as well)

The type I want to pass to the table as a `dataSource` is this

```
export interface OrderToProcess{
  Id: string,
  Amount: number,
  Currency: string
}
```

How do I go about converting one type into the other, I've tried `filter()` `map()` `object.entries()` and I'm sure I'm not using them right but none seem to do what I am after.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed looking for [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map). Assuming we have the following function to mock your HTTP call:

```js
  // Imports needed for rest of example code
  import { map, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

  /**
   * getPaymentIntents mocks HTTP call with static data
   */
  getPaymentIntents(): Observable<any> {
    return of([
      {
        id: 'pi_3K4B432423dqM1gTYncsL',
        amount: 2000,
        amount_capturable: 0,
        amount_received: 0,
        application: null,
        canceled_at: null,
        cancellation_reason: null,
        created: 1638911287,
        currency: 'usd',
        customer: 'cus_KjDBkdsaHIT6AN',
      },
      {
        id: 'pi_3K4BW7EE9YQoA1qM1gTYncsL',
        amount: 1000,
        amount_capturable: 0,
        amount_received: 0,
        application: null,
        canceled_at: null,
        cancellation_reason: null,
        created: 1638913687,
        currency: 'usd',
        customer: 'cus_KjDBkxEVHIT6AN',
      },
    ]);
  }
}
```

You can map to your type in your component using the following (or something similar:

```js
  // Table columns
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'amount', 'currency'];
  // Our table data source
  dataSource$: Observable<OrderToProcess[]>;
  constructor() {
    this.dataSource$ = this.getPaymentIntents().pipe(
      // Map data to an array of type OrderToProcess.
      map((data) => {
        let transformedData: OrderToProcess[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          transformedData.push({
            Id: data[i].id,
            Amount: data[i].amount,
            Currency: data[i].currency,
          });
        }
        return transformedData;
      })
    );
  }
```

And to display them in your table:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource$" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Id}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Amount</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Amount}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="currency">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Currency</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Currency}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

If you paste this in to your project I believe it should help you accomplish what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you just need to do this:

TS

```
...
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...

// Declare your interface before declaring your Class, right after your imports
export interface OrderToProcess{
  Id: string,
  Amount: number,
  Currency: string
}

...
// In your class attributes declaration
dataSource$: Observable<OrderToProcess[]>;
...

constructor() {

    this.dataSource$ = this.getPaymentIntents()
    .pipe(
      map( (data:Payment[]) => {

        let ordersToProcess: OrderToProcess[] = data.map( payment => 
           {
              Id: payment.id,
              Amount: payment.amount,
              Currency: payment.currency
           }
        );

        return ordersToProcess;

      }) //end map rxjs
    ); //end pipe rxjs

}
```

Then, in your HTML just pass the dataSource$ observable to your material table as usual ([dataSource]="dataSource$")

NOTE: I'm not completely sure, but maybe you can even simplify it further just by doing the following:

```
 this.dataSource$ = this.getPaymentIntents()
    .pipe(
      map( (data:Payment[]) => data.map( payment => 
           {
              Id: payment.id,
              Amount: payment.amount,
              Currency: payment.currency
           }
    )));
```